# How to Test GPT-4 LLM Response in a C# .NET Application Without Using Prompt Flow?

Tags: gpt-4, semantic-kernel, azure-promptflow

we’ve integrated semantic kernel with GPT-4 to interact with a C# .NET application. However, I’ve encountered a challenge: Prompt flow does not support the C# language, but I still want to test the LLM response.

Is there any way to accomplish this without using the prompt flow? Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

At present, I do not have idea, how can I validate LLM response using a variety of user input just in the same way prompt flow evaluates the model.